# Call method of parent when child is dynamically inserted

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a "modal" component and another element to dynamically insert "childs" on this modal. How do I to call a method of parent element from child of modal:

```
class Parent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            'view_addevent': false,
        };

        this.addEventAdHoc = this.addEventAdHoc.bind(this);
        this.closeEventAdHoc = this.closeEventAdHoc.bind(this);
        this.searchAdHocEvent = this.searchAdHocEvent(this);
    }

    addEventAdHoc() {
        this.setState({ view_addevent: true });
    }

    closeEventAdHoc() {
        this.setState({ view_addevent: false })
    }

    searchAdHocEvent(event) {
        console.log(event.keyCode);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <main id='main-content'>
                <Modal show={this.state.view_addevent} autocomplete={ this.searchAdHocEvent } close={ this.closeEventAdHoc }>
                    <div className='form-group'>
                        <input id='event-adhoc-search' onKeyPress={(e) => this.props.autocomplete(e) } className='form-control' type='text' />
                    </div>
                </Modal>
            </main>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding your question based on the code you've shown, but, generally if you need to reference a parent element from a child node, you have to link the child to the parent and not just parent to child.

Something like: `parent.addChild = child => { child.parent = parent; parent.child = child }`

Comment: Could you share part of your code that dynamically inserts the child? I do not see it above.

Comment: i'm sorry, after many many proof, just i resolve the problem, i missing ".bind" on parent constructor for "searchAdHocEvent" method... i'm a principiant with reactjs and es6, but now work perfectly, many thanks!